# PC with Windows 8.1 boots from any key pressed

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, keyboard, shutdown

so I recently acquired and installed Windows 8.1 on my PC and yesterday I noticed that, while my PC is supposedly turned off, I can turn it on by pressing any key on the keyboard. I assume this is because Windows 8.1 doesn't completely shut down, even though it seems so (there are no leds turned on/blinking).

I can't reproduce this behavior if I shut it down by pulling the plug, by holding the power button for a few seconds or by issuing the command 'shutdown /s /t 0' in Windows CMD. In these cases I have to turn it on by pressing the power button (as it should). This didn't happen with the previous OS (Windows 7).

Motherboard is an Asus Maximus IV GENE-Z. The option to boot up by keyboard is disabled, and the EuP Ready option is enabled. My keyboard is plugged in by a PS/2 port.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the machine is just waking up

Comment: Looks like it, but I am turning it off using the 'Shut down' option. There are no lights that remain on, nothing to indicate the PC is suspended/sleeping.

Comment: try running powercfg -list it should give you some idea

Comment: Windows 8 be default does a hybrid shutdown.  You don't want your computer to do this? Use the command that works to actually shutdown your system

Comment: Pretty sure its called Fast Startup..
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft chose to add an option to Windows that already could be done without this new option and then defaulted this new option on.  This new option causes the computer to go into Hybrid Sleep (S4) state when the Shutdown button or Shutdown soft button is pressed.  This means the computer is not in a complete Shutdown (S5) state which short of disconnecting the wall current is a total shutdown state or one could call it the Standby state as even in a Complete Shutdown (S5) state power is still being supplied to the motherboard if only to run the clock and UEFI/BIOS to keep the battery from draining. This was mostly done for the Laptop and Tablet users who want near instant on while not draining their batteries.

You can defeat this Hybrid Sleep (S4) state by going to Control Panel/System And Security/Power Options. Click on Choose what the power buttons do. Click on Change settings that are currently unavailable.  Then clear the checkmark from Turn on fast startup (recommended).  This will restore the Complete Shutdown (S5) state function, we are all familiar with, and allow your computer to do a complete shutdown.

Comment: This look like a complaint rather than an answer. Please can you [edit] your answer to just include the essential information and remove the opinion part?

Comment: It is now factual and informative and I believe no further change is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your keyboard. That worked for me.**
I tryed everything. In bios (well, something like bios my new pc has now), power settings, everything. Actually, i had a classic white microsoft keyboard on my pc and i haven't noticed anything. I thing the problem started when i changed the keyboard with a new one (i wanted a black one (not microsoft)). I used to find my pc open and i thought at first that i haven't turned it off properly. When i realised the problem, i googled it, i tried everything, and last night i thought of the idea to have my old keyboard back. And... problem solved!! Some other thing that i noticed the first time i changed the keyboard, is that after booting, the pc made the noise that makes when you put a new usb device (every time). Now, no sounds. Maybe it has something to do with that... i don't know...
I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Which button are you pressing or process you are using to shut down your computer from Windows 10?

You can try these to see if one of them work:

Check these areas in your bios-

Advanced-->USB configuration-->EHCI hand-off-->Disabled

APM Configuration-->Power on By/PS2 Keyboard-->Disabled

APM Configuration-->Power on By/PS2 Mouse-->Disabled

-----------------------------------------------------------------

Disable Fast Startup - [Turn off fast startup.bat](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/12686d1424036052-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a-turn_off_fast_startup.bat) - Run as Admin.  Then reboot when it finishes.
 To enable fast startup you can run this the same way - [Turn on fast startup.bat](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/12687d1424036052-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a-turn_on_fast_startup.bat)

The .bat files below will change the registry key and value below.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power
HiberbootEnabled 

DWORD:    
0 = Turn off fast startup
1 = Turn on fast startup
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------
Disable hibernation (will also disable fast startup) - Open Command Prompt as Admin enter this (to enable use 'on') -

`powercfg -h off`

Sources:
[How to Turn On or Off Fast Startup - tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)
[How to Enable or Disable Hibernate - tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

---

These steps could help you get more information if needed:
You could try booting into safe mode, shutting down and seeing if your computer will still wake/power on to tell if it is something related to your software; alternatively you could also use a live linux usb or some other bootable usb device, shutdown your computer through that and if it still wakes/powers on by pressing your keyboard you know it is not related to Windows but is either bios.  I would also unplug your current keyboard and use a different one to see if it still wakes.  If you have a PS2 keyboard plug and adapter/ps2 keyboard, trying the keyboard in there will tell you if it is related to USB.