# Preventing ASUS BIOS from booting when I press keyboard

Tags: boot, keyboard, bios

My (brand new) ASUS BIOS boots my machine when I press my (PS/2) keyboard, and I want to get rid of this "feature," but I can't seem to find a setting for it in the BIOS menus. Can it be done?

The motherboard is an ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC., Z97-P, Rev X.0x.

(I'm running Windows 10 btw, but I doubt that makes any difference. Yes, I'm shutting down, not hybernating. Both states will boot on keypress.)

Comment: What motherboard do you have? The setting should be in your BIOS settings, probably under boot options.

Comment: It looks like your PC is just waking-up! Are you sure you shut it down rather then hibernate it?

Comment: @duDE: yes I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked these parts of your bios?
Advanced-->USB configuration-->EHCI hand-off-->Disabled
 
APM Configuration-->Power on By/PS2 Keyboard-->Disabled
 
APM Configuration-->Power on By/PS2 Mouse-->Disabled

Also check my answer here - https://superuser.com/a/1096251/195168

Windows 10 has a 'hybrid shutdown' feature which could be part of the reason this is happening. However my first guess would be a bios setting.  If the bios settings are not enabled to boot by keyboard, try shutting down your computer in an Admin Command Prompt with `shutdown /p` to see if your computer still boots when pressing the keyboard.

[Shut Down Computer in Windows 10 - tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7418-shut-down-computer-windows-10-a.html)